# Enumerate k-combinations in Clojure (P26 from 99 problems)

Tags: clojure, combinatorics

I've been playing with Clojure for the last few evenings, going through the well known 99 problems (I'm using [a set adapted for Scala](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)).

> **Problem 26**
>
> Given a set *S* and a no. of items *K*, returns all possible
>   combinations of *K* items that can be taken from set *S*.

Here's my solution:

```
(defn combinations [k s]
  (cond
    (> k (count s)) nil        ;not enough items in sequence to form a valid combination
    (= k (count s)) [s]        ;only one combination available: all items 
    (= 1 k) (map vector s)     ;every item (on its own) is a valid combination
    :else (reduce concat (map-indexed 
            (fn [i x] (map #(cons x %) (combinations (dec k) (drop (inc i) s)))) 
            s))))

(combinations 3 ['a 'b 'c 'd 'f])
```

My basic solution is to take each item from the given sequence (`map-indexed`) and recurse to generate combinations of size `K - 1` from the remaining sequence. The termination conditions are described above.

I'm still a complete Clojure newbie and would welcome comments on structure, efficiency, readability, resemblance to idiomatic Clojure, etc. Feel free to be brutal, but please remember I've been doing Clojure for only a few hours :)

I'm less interested in alternative mathematical methods for generating *k*-combinations, more interested in feedback on whether this is passable Clojure.

Comment: Check how it is done in math.combinatorics https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L69

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently reading "Joy of Clojure" so I'm (very) far from being "fluent" in Clojure but what I noticed is:

- your solution is clever but quite complicated, you use "imperative" habits like indexed iteration
- try to keep with simple abstractions like sequence **first** and **rest** and the solution will work with any Clojure collection - see example below
- your solution use **cond** with three checks for **k** - consider using **condp**

Here's my code:

```
(defn subsets [n items]
(cond
    (= n 0) '(())
    (empty? items) '()
    :else (concat (map
                    #(cons (first items) %)
                    (subsets (dec n) (rest items)))
                  (subsets n (rest items)))))
```